# Converting slow LEFT JOINs to UNIONs

Tags: mysql

I had a query that was taking 5.5s.

```
SELECT *, chv_images.image_id FROM chv_images

LEFT JOIN chv_storages ON chv_images.image_storage_id = chv_storages.storage_id
LEFT JOIN chv_users ON chv_images.image_user_id = chv_users.user_id
LEFT JOIN chv_albums ON chv_images.image_album_id = chv_albums.album_id
LEFT JOIN chv_categories ON chv_images.image_category_id = chv_categories.category_id
LEFT JOIN chv_meta ON chv_images.image_id = chv_meta.image_id

WHERE chv_images.image_nsfw = 0 AND (chv_albums.album_privacy NOT IN ('private','private_but_link','custom') OR chv_albums.album_privacy IS NULL OR chv_albums.album_user_id IS NULL)
ORDER BY chv_images.image_id DESC
LIMIT 0,15
```

Optimized, the query takes 0.002 seconds. Great!

```
(
SELECT image_name, image_extension, image_date, image_date_gmt, image_nsfw, image_title, image_user_id, image_album_id, image_storage_mode, image_storage_id, image_views, image_category_id, image_chain, image_format, image_likes, image_center, image_zscore, image_enabled_zscore, image_update_cache, chv_images.image_id FROM chv_images
LEFT JOIN chv_albums ON chv_images.image_album_id = chv_albums.album_id WHERE chv_images.image_nsfw = 0 AND (chv_albums.album_user_id IS NULL)
ORDER BY chv_images.image_id DESC
LIMIT 0,15
)
UNION
DISTINCT
(
SELECT image_name, image_extension, image_date, image_date_gmt, image_nsfw, image_title, image_user_id, image_album_id, image_storage_mode, image_storage_id, image_views, image_category_id, image_chain, image_format, image_likes, image_center, image_zscore, image_enabled_zscore, image_update_cache, chv_images.image_id FROM chv_images
LEFT JOIN chv_albums ON chv_images.image_album_id = chv_albums.album_id WHERE chv_images.image_nsfw = 0 AND (chv_albums.album_privacy NOT IN ("private", "private_but_link", "custom") OR chv_albums.album_privacy IS NULL)
ORDER BY chv_images.image_id DESC
LIMIT 0,15
)
ORDER BY image_id DESC
LIMIT 0,15
```

The problem is, the new query only JOINS two tables. The output is missing columns that are needed. I did try adding more UNIONs for the other LEFT JOINs that are missing from the new query. I'd get close after fixing error after error (like matching column sizes), but no cigar.

[See CREATE TABLE](https://pastebin.com/ggbdWHTk)

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

Best query based on first query (no UNION) looks like this. 3.5 seconds.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT chv_images.image_id, chv_images.image_name, chv_images.image_extension, chv_images.image_date, chv_images.image_date_gmt, chv_images.image_nsfw, chv_images.image_title, chv_images.image_user_id, chv_images.image_album_id, chv_images.image_storage_mode, chv_images.image_storage_id, chv_images.image_views, chv_images.image_category_id, chv_images.image_chain, chv_images.image_format FROM chv_images

LEFT JOIN chv_storages ON chv_images.image_storage_id = chv_storages.storage_id
LEFT JOIN chv_users ON chv_images.image_user_id = chv_users.user_id
LEFT JOIN chv_albums ON chv_images.image_album_id = chv_albums.album_id
LEFT JOIN chv_categories ON chv_images.image_category_id = chv_categories.category_id
LEFT JOIN chv_meta ON chv_images.image_id = chv_meta.image_id

WHERE chv_images.image_nsfw = 0 AND (chv_albums.album_privacy NOT IN ('private','private_but_link','custom') OR chv_albums.album_privacy IS NULL OR chv_albums.album_user_id IS NULL)
               ) images, chv_storages
ORDER BY image_id DESC
LIMIT 0,15
```

***UPDATE 2***

Above query takes 2.6 seconds if "LEFT JOIN chv_meta ON chv_images.image_id = chv_meta.image_id" is removed.

Comment: Typically, a `JOIN` is used to project more data (and widens your result rows), whereas a `UNION` is used to increase your result set (i.e. # rows).  Are you trying to use a `UNION` to increase performance?  Are you getting an error message?

Comment: What happened was that I ran the first query above through eversql's free query optimizer. The optimized query looked similar to the second query, but didn't work out of the box. My previous question on here was answered and pointed me in the right direction. Which is how I got to the second query above. At first glance, it looked like the second query was producing the desired result (the same results as first query above just faster). This is not so. I'm trying to get better performance on query #1, which does output correctly but very slow. Thanks! @ravioli

Comment: Eversql's optimizer dropped the other JOINs. Why? I don't know, but some googling leads me to think it is a limitation with UNION. In which case, how do I get around that limitation? @ravioli

Comment: I did read something about a hacky solution of adding null columns to the other joins tables. Perhaps eversql's optimizer didn't include the other JOINs because the column size doesn't match? I really don't know though.

Comment: A couple things on your original query:

- instead of `SELECT *`, you should only return the columns you need...doing lots of joins like you have may be returning very wide rows.  Not sure when the `LIMIT` is applied, but your DBMS may be carrying around this wide rows in spool before returning the final LIMITed result set.  Also, anything you can change from `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN` may help.

Comment: Also, eliminate any unneeded joins...if you can eliminate any of the `OR` conditions in your `WHERE` clause, that may help.  Do you have an EXPLAIN or equivalent you can post, so we see what your query engine's trying to do under-the-covers?

Comment: 1) The first thing I tried was optimizing the SELECT * by replacing it with columns on the original query. It wasn't much faster so I looked into eversql. Also I did experiment with using INNER JOINS. It breaks the desired result.

Comment: 2) I cannot eliminate any of the conditions or joins, only rewrite them like in the second query with the UNIONs. Which EXPLAIN do you want to see?

Comment: Can you run the EXPLAIN on the original slow query with the joins?

Comment: How many rows in each table?  Do you have any indexes defined?

Comment: Added explains.

Comment: See answer above.

Comment: What is your question? PS 1 Please do not clarify in comments, edit your post. 2 Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. 3 Please read & act on [mcve]. PS Read the manual re indexing & optimization. That includes EXPLAIN & indexing appropriate to your ordering by image_id & DESC. Also learn what LEFT JOIN & UNION do.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not a mysql expert, so this is just general guidance here.

Looking at the `EXPLAIN`, it's probably related to your `chv_images` table since it's got 178K rows and all the other tables are joining to it.  A couple things to try:

- try removing parts of the query one-by-one to see what may be causing the delay:

  - take out the `ORDER BY` (maybe the sort is taking forever)
  - remove the `LEFT JOINs` one by one and see where performance degrades
- try using a window function instead of `LIMIT`

A couple links to look at:

[`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html#explain-extra-information)

[`LIMIT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/limit-optimization.html)

I'd say to check the documentation for `EXPLAIN` and look at what the query plan's trying to do with your `chv_images` table.

**Update**
I checked all the tables you are joining and it looks like the joins are all done on unique keys (i.e. 1-1).  Since you want to order by the `image_id` field in the `chv_images` table, you should be able to do a sub-select for the rows you want from that table first before doing any of your joins.  Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    chv_images.image_id, 
    chv_images.image_name, 
    chv_images.image_extension, 
    chv_images.image_date, 
    chv_images.image_date_gmt, 
    chv_images.image_nsfw, 
    chv_images.image_title, 
    chv_images.image_user_id, 
    chv_images.image_album_id, 
    chv_images.image_storage_mode, 
    chv_images.image_storage_id, 
    chv_images.image_views, 
    chv_images.image_category_id, 
    chv_images.image_chain, 
    chv_images.image_format 
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            img.*, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY img.image_id DESC) RowNum -- Assign a rank to each row, ordered by image_id
        FROM chv_images img
    ) src
    WHERE RowNum <= 15 -- Only return first 15 rows
) chv_images
--  FROM chv_images                                                                         -- Primary Key = image_id
LEFT JOIN chv_storages ON chv_images.image_storage_id = chv_storages.storage_id             -- Primary Key = NULL, Unique Key = storage_id
LEFT JOIN chv_users ON chv_images.image_user_id = chv_users.user_id                         -- Primary Key = user_id
LEFT JOIN chv_albums ON chv_images.image_album_id = chv_albums.album_id                     -- Primary Key = album_id
LEFT JOIN chv_categories ON chv_images.image_category_id = chv_categories.category_id       -- Primary Key = category_id
LEFT JOIN chv_meta ON chv_images.image_id = chv_meta.image_id                               -- Primary Key = id, Key = image_id
WHERE chv_images.image_nsfw = 0 
AND (
    chv_albums.album_privacy NOT IN ('private','private_but_link','custom') OR 
    chv_albums.album_privacy IS NULL OR 
    chv_albums.album_user_id IS NULL
)
ORDER BY image_id DESC
-- LIMIT 0,15
```

This should be equivalent to doing the `LIMIT` at the end, since all your joins are being done on `UNIQUE` keys.  Keep in mind, if your query / DDL ever change so that the joins are not 1-1, then the behavior of this query may also change.  Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: For the first query, the ORDER BY is taking forever. How do I have the same effect without ORDER BY? edit: I'll look into it and award this as the answer. Although I would like to know how to fix the second query.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you. It has an error, but the idea looks right. "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(ORDER BY img.image_id DESC) RowNum FROM chv_images img ) src W' at line 22"

Comment: Line 22 is: ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY img.image_id DESC) RowNum

Comment: @Shadow Aww shucks.

Comment: @Shadow is upgrading from mysql 5.6 to 8.0 trivial/recommended/the only solution?

Comment: I would not recommend to upgrade to 8.0, if your application is in production. As I wrote, 8.0 is still in alpha status. According to the table schemas, you do not have appropriate indexes defined, which lead to the using temporary, using filesort in the explain. Fix that and you should see improvement in the query speed.